# How to properly use std::function as a predicate

Tags: c++, templates, predicate, std-function

I want to use std::function as a predicate in a templated helper function but I get an error:

> ```
> main.cpp(15): error C2672: 'Any': no matching overloaded function found
> main.cpp(15): error C2784: 'bool Any(const std::vector<T,std::allocator<_Ty>> &,const std::function<bool(const T &)>)': could not deduce template argument for 'const
> std::function<bool(const T &)>' from 'main::<lambda_1b47ff228a1af9c86629c77c82b319f9>'
> main.cpp(7): note: see declaration of 'Any'
> ```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
bool Any(const std::vector<T>& list, const std::function<bool(const T&)> predicate)
{   
    return std::any_of(list.begin(), list.end(), [&](const T& t) { return predicate(t); });
}

int main()
{
    auto myList = std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    if (Any(myList, [](int i) { return i % 5 == 0; }))
    {
        std::cout << "Bingo!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Not found :(" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don't see a need for the overhead of `std::function` here. Just use normal template parameter for the predicate: `template <typename T, typename Predicate>
bool Any(const std::vector<T>& list, Predicate predicate)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
bool Any(const std::vector<T>& list, const std::function<bool(const T&)> predicate)
{   
    return std::any_of(list.begin(), list.end(), [&](const T& t) { return predicate(t); });
}

int main()
{
    auto myList = std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    if (Any<int>(myList, [](int i) -> bool { return i % 5 == 0; }))
    {
        std::cout << "Bingo!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Not found :(" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`if (Any<int>(myList, [](int i) -> bool { return i % 5 == 0; }))`

1. You need to specify template argument (Any)
2. You forgot to add return type of lambda

Comment: An explicit return type isn't necessary. It compiles fine without it.

Comment: Indeed, specifying <int> was the key: very little code modification fixed the whole issue, thanks! And yes, the explicit return type is maybe good for following clean code best practices but not necessary if one doesn't want it.

Comment: @MatX @Zoe Agree, sometimes, compilers are not `smart` enough.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

You're passing a lambda to `Any`, but the implicit conversion (from lambda to `std::function`) won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction), which makes `T` can't be deduced on the 2nd function argument.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), which happens later.

You can use [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) (since C++20) to exclude the 2nd argument from deduction; then the template parameter `T` would be deduced on only the 1st argument, then the code works fine. e.g.

```
template <typename T>
bool Any(const std::vector<T>& list, const std::function<bool(const std::type_identity_t<T>&)> predicate)
//                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{   
    return std::any_of(list.begin(), list.end(), [&](const T& t) { return predicate(t); });
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/e19nofXemjwh2zvo)

If you can't apply C++20, you can refer to the linked page above which gives a possible implementation, it's not hard to implement your own `type_identity`. If you don't stick to `std::function`, you can just add another template parameter for predicate.

```
template <typename T, typename P>
bool Any(const std::vector<T>& list, P predicate)
{   
    return std::any_of(list.begin(), list.end(), predicate);
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bZREugmtaGZIg1Ha)

Or make it more general to work with other containers or raw arrays.

```
template <typename C, typename P>
bool Any(const C& c, P predicate)
{   
    return std::any_of(std::begin(c), std::end(c), predicate);
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kRhVQ0zYeuWFuTtc)

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to use C++20 because I will have to target many platforms, and there is no guarantee that they will have all the latest and greatest features. Do I have to use some other approach then? Maybe a function pointer or something?

Comment: @MatX Make any of your constraints chrystal clear in your question please.

Comment: @MatX Answer revised. BTW: You'll have the similar issue with function pointer.

Comment: I haven't thought of adding a second type parameter, but it's a good point. I'll remember it.

Comment: In the last example, the code could be made more generic as follows: `using std::begin; using std::end; return std::any_of(begin(c), end(c), predicate);` -- Advantage: allows the `Any` function to be called for non-standard types for which custom `begin` and `end` overloads exist (basically merges the overload sets of `std` and any custom overloads).